# Count the cycle, and count that already has been counted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have my query:

```
SELECT UserGroupCode,COUNT(UserGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle]
FROM Users.GroupCycles
GROUP BY UserGroupCode;
```

Which shows me:

```
UserGroupCode CountofCycles
1                   1
4                   1
5                   1
6                   2  (gone into 2nd cycle)
7                   1
8                   1
9                   1
10                  1
11                  1
12                  1
13                  1
14                  1
15                  1
16                  1
17                  1
18                  1
19                  1
```

When i try to count Total UserGroups where countofcycle=1

```
SELECT Count(t.CountOfCycle) AS 'totalgroups'
FROM 
    (SELECT CreateDate, COUNT(userGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle] 
     FROM Users.GroupCycles 
    GROUP BY CreateDate,UserGroupCode)t
WHERE CountofCycle=1
```

I get result = 18 which should be 16, if i delete CreateDate from both SELECT And GROUP BY statement i can get correct number of CountofCycles,
and when i change condition to CountofCycle=2 or >1 it shows me 0

What is the problem with showing UserGroups with cycle > 1 ???!??

Here is my query to filter out onCreateDate, in 2nd table that i UNION with 1st one, i cant't use CreateDate, as it disturbs my query results

```
SELECT Count(t.CountOfCycle) AS 'total groups' 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(userGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle], CreateDate
     FROM users.GroupCycles GROUP BY userGroupCode,CreateDate)t
WHERE t.CountOfCycle=1 AND t.CreateDate Between '03/16/2017' AND '04/25/2017'


UNION ALL

SELECT Count(t.CountOfCycle) AS 'group on date2'
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(userGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle] FROM users.GroupCycles GROUP BY  userGroupCode)t
WHERE t.CountOfCycle=2
```

Comment: Your first query and second query are different. In the first you only group by `UserGroupCode` whereas in the second you group by `CreateDate` as well. It is more than likely that with this second level of grouping there just aren’t any records with a count of 2 or more.

Comment: You have said *"if i delete CreateDate from both SELECT And GROUP BY statement i can get correct number of CountofCycles"*, so what is the problem? Why are you adding `CreateDate` to the select and the group by if you know it is giving you the wrong results?

Comment: I need CreateDate to filter groups by CreationDate

Comment: How are you filtering on `CreateDate`? Can you post your final query?
 Could you not do this within the subquery, so you don't need to include it in the group by?

Comment: Yes, please check above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to address why you are not getting the results you are expecting, and the simple reason is that you are comparing two different queries and expecting the results to be the same.

Consider this very simple example data

```
UserGroupCode   |   CreateDate
----------------+----------------
    A           |   2017-05-10
    B           |   2017-05-10
    B           |   2017-05-11
    C           |   2017-05-10
```

You have two records where the `UserGroupCode` is `B`, so if you run:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (UserGroupCode CHAR(1), CreateDate DATE)
INSERT @T (userGroupCode, CreateDate) 
VALUES ('A', '2017-05-10'), ('B', '2017-05-10'), ('B', '2017-05-11');

SELECT  UserGroupCode, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM    @T
GROUP BY UserGroupCode
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This returns:

```
UserGroupCode   Count
-------------------------
    B           2
```

However, if you were to add `CreateDate` to the grouping, "B" would be split into two groups, each with a count of 1:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (UserGroupCode CHAR(1), CreateDate DATE)
INSERT @T (userGroupCode, CreateDate) 
VALUES ('A', '2017-05-10'), ('B', '2017-05-10'), ('B', '2017-05-11');

SELECT  UserGroupCode, CreateDate, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM    @T
WHERE   UserGroupCode = 'B'
GROUP BY UserGroupCode, CreateDate;
```

This returns:

```
UserGroupCode   CreateDate      Count
---------------------------------------
    B           2017-05-10      1
    B           2017-05-11      1
```

Now, based you your queries you have posted, it looks like you want to know

1. The number of groups that only have one record in the date range 16th March 2017 to 25th April 2017.
2. The number of groups that have two records in total.

For this, consider a slightly larger data set:

```
UserGroupCode   |   CreateDate
----------------+----------------
    A           |   2017-04-10
    B           |   2017-04-10
    B           |   2017-05-11
    C           |   2017-01-01
    C           |   2017-01-02
    D           |   2017-04-01
    D           |   2017-04-02
    E           |   2017-01-02
```

So here.

- Group A has one record in total, and it falls within the date range
- Group B has two records in total, on in the date range, one not
- Group C has two records, neither in the date range
- Group D has two records, both in the date range.
- Group E has one record, not in the date range

So for your first requirement:

1. The number of groups that only have one record in the date range 16th March 2017 to 25th April 2017.

We would expect 2 groups, A and B, because C and E have no records in the date range, and D has two.

and the second we would expect three groups, B, C and D, since A and E only have one record each.

You can do this with a single query by using a conditional aggregate.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (UserGroupCode CHAR(1), CreateDate DATE)
INSERT @T (userGroupCode, CreateDate) 
VALUES ('A', '2017-04-10'), 
        ('B', '2017-04-10'), ('B', '2017-05-11'), 
        ('C', '2017-01-01'), ('C', '2017-01-02'),
        ('D', '2017-04-01'), ('D', '2017-04-02'),
        ('E', '2017-01-02');

SELECT  TotalGroups = COUNT(CASE WHEN RecordsInPeriod = 1 THEN 1 END),
        GroupOnDate2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN TotalRecords = 2 THEN 1 END)
FROM    (   SELECT  UserGroupCode,
                    TotalRecords = COUNT(*),
                    RecordsInPeriod = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreateDate >= '20170316'
                                                AND CreateDate <= '20170425' THEN 1 END)
            FROM    @T
            GROUP BY UserGroupCode
        ) AS t;
```

Which gives:

```
TotalGroups     GroupOnDate2
------------------------------
    2               3
```

Comment: You just made my day way more happier, THANK YOU so much!

Comment: Last question, GroupOnDate2 if i instead of Count(*) will put TotalRecords = COUNT(CASE WHEN CreateDate = '04/17/2017' THEN 2 END) 
will it show me the date i inserted, and CountofCycles that is >2 , will it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HAVING`, should work (and be more efficient)

```
select count(*)
from
(
SELECT CreateDate, COUNT(userGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle] 
FROM Users.GroupCycles 
GROUP BY CreateDate,UserGroupCode
having count(userGroupCode) > 1 -- here is HAVING clause
) x1
```

Comment: I don't disagree that `HAVING` is a more concise solution, but it wouldn't be more efficient. SQL Server is smart enough to work out that both queries mean the same thing, and therefore generates the same plan - http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8a397bba5651e1b27a1b86f8512ff0a8

Comment: I am having issue with last parentheses, it says Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @TilekN. Yeh, my bad, alias the subquery and it works

Comment: Nope, does not work, its same query as mine. HAVING statement does not strongly specify the condition and it just gives me either null or 0

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect to see a `HAVING` clause rather than a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT UserGroupCode, COUNT(UserGroupCode) [CountofCycle]
FROM [Users].[GroupCycles]
GROUP BY UserGroupCode
HAVING COUNT(UserGroupCode) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks,but i already counted it, i need to count the result as you can see above (2nd query)

Comment: Ah, in that case use the nested query answer (or a view?)

Comment: That's where i need help, can you show it please, if you dont mind